# Request Facebook to investigate which administrator made page post

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I'm an administrator of a Facebook Page for an organisation that has multiple administrators. Recently another administrator posted some false information on the organisation's Facebook page which has led to serious accusations of deliberate sabotage of another member of the board and has led to some very heated words being exchanged at meetings, etc.

So far no one has admitted to making the post and I have the feeling no one ever will. To put an end to the issue it would obviously help if we could identify who made the post in question.

Is there any way I can request that Facebook check out who made this post?

As a safety measure all other administrators have now been removed from the page and the post in question and has now been removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not familiar with the specifics of Facebook and libel law (and am certainly not a lawyer), Facebook will really only be willing to intervene if this situation is subject to some form of [legal liability](http://www.dmlp.org/legal-guide/publishing-information-harms-anothers-reputation) (vis-a-vis defamation I would imagine - you can see the Electronic Frontier Foundation's [Online Defamation Law](https://www.eff.org/issues/bloggers/legal/liability/defamation) for case examples).

If this is the situation, law enforcement or government entities associated with legal proceedings pursuant to Title 18, United States Code, Sections 2703 and 2711 may request access to records from Facebook. According to Facebook's [Law Enforcement Online Requests](https://www.facebook.com/records)

> **Request Secure Access to the Law Enforcement Online Request System**
>
> Facebook discloses account records solely in accordance with our terms
>   of service and applicable law.
>
> If you are a law enforcement agent who
>   is authorized to gather evidence in connection with an official
>   investigation, you may request records from Facebook through this
>   system.

See Facebook's [Law Enforcement Guidelines](https://www.facebook.com/safety/groups/law/guidelines/) for more detail about specific scenarios and US Legal Process Requirements (or international, depending on your location).

Since this problem applies specifically to your Facebook Page you may also want to see the [Facebook Pages Terms of Service](https://www.facebook.com/page_guidelines.php).

Also note that the specifics may vary according to your state law.